# After update of tor, unable to start tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, debian, update

I am on Debian and getting Debian from Debian itself after which it updates tor from the web.

Now the path of Tor Browser has changed slightly it seems from

```
/home/shirish/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser
```

it has now changed to

```
/home/shirish/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/start-tor-browser.desktop
```

Trying to launch it I get the following -

```
[$] ./start-tor-browser.desktop                                                                                                     
Launching './Browser/start-tor-browser --detach'...
./Browser/execdesktop: line 14: ./Browser/start-tor-browser: No such file or directory
```

Update -

Trying to launch it with torbrowser-launcher I get the same error -

```
[$] torbrowser-launcher                                                                                                             
Tor Browser Launcher
By Micah Lee, licensed under MIT
version 0.2.7
https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher
Launching './Browser/start-tor-browser --detach'...
./Browser/execdesktop: line 14: ./Browser/start-tor-browser: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: This is `torbrowser-launcher` that you're using? (it's totally unrelated to the `tor` package on apt). Have you tried opening it using the `torbrowser-launcher` program itself?

Comment: I updated my query with the info. you asked, the result is the same. I could simply remove tor and the related binaries and try afresh but would like to do as a last resort.

Comment: does the file `/home/shirish/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser` exist?

Comment: it existed before, now it does not, after the update, hence the question what to do.

Comment: Reinstall Tor Browser